# xml construct error

Tags: xml, syntax

I have the following xml file as output from a program:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<rsp stat='ok'>
<results total='5'>
<result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjMyOTM4MDMxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjIyNzExOA@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='The Amazing Spider-Man 'year='2012' director='Marc Webb' rating='7.3' details='/title/tt0948470/' />
<result cover='http://i.media-imdb.com/images/SF1f0a42ee1aa08d477a576fbbf7562eed/realm/feature.gif' title='The Amazing Spider-Man 2 'year='2014' director='Marc Webb' rating='N.A.' details='/title/tt1872181/'/>
<result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzk3MTE5MDU5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjY3NTY3._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='Spider-Man 'year='2002' director='Sam Raimi' rating='7.3' details='/title/tt0145487/'/>
<result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODUwMDc5Mzc5M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDgzOTY0MQ@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='Spider-Man 3 'year='2007' director='Sam Raimi' rating='6.3' details='/title/tt0413300/'/>
<result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE1ODcyODYxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA1NDE3MQ@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='Spider-Man 2 'year='2004' director='Sam Raimi' rating='7.5' details='/title/tt0316654/'/>
</results>
</rsp>
```

But when i save it as xml file and open it in browser it shows attribute construct error. WHY ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to separate attribute values from the names of other attributes with whitespace characters. Notice that `year` immediately follows the value of `title`. You simply misplaced a couple of spaces.

`title='The Amazing Spider-Man 'year='2012'`

You have to change it to

`title='The Amazing Spider-Man' year='2012'`

The following document should render properly.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<rsp stat='ok'>
  <results total='5'>
    <result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjMyOTM4MDMxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjIyNzExOA@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='The Amazing Spider-Man' year='2012' director='Marc Webb' rating='7.3' details='/title/tt0948470/' />
    <result cover='http://i.media-imdb.com/images/SF1f0a42ee1aa08d477a576fbbf7562eed/realm/feature.gif' title='The Amazing Spider-Man 2' year='2014' director='Marc Webb' rating='N.A.' details='/title/tt1872181/'/>
    <result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzk3MTE5MDU5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjY3NTY3._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='Spider-Man' year='2002' director='Sam Raimi' rating='7.3' details='/title/tt0145487/'/>
    <result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODUwMDc5Mzc5M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDgzOTY0MQ@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='Spider-Man 3' year='2007' director='Sam Raimi' rating='6.3' details='/title/tt0413300/'/>
    <result cover='http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE1ODcyODYxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA1NDE3MQ@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg' title='Spider-Man 2' year='2004' director='Sam Raimi' rating='7.5' details='/title/tt0316654/'/>
  </results>
</rsp>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a space before each attribute. (You forgot one at "year")